# Angular.js directive, attrs shows the attribute from the markup but can't reference it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the snippet below which is a directive for jQuery highcharts:

```
return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  priority: 0,
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    // console.log(attrs);
    var ga = JSON.parse(attrs.ga);

    // defines the options for the highcharts graph and uses data from the ga attr
    var options = {...};

    elem.highcharts(options);

  }
}
```

When logging the `attrs` to the console, I see the output:

```
{
  $$element: n.fn.init[1],
  $$observers: Object,
  $attr: Object,
  ga: "{"my": "json"}"
}
```

However, when I then try to do a `console.log(attrs.ga)`, I get `Unexpected end of input` when doing `JSON.parse()` and I get `null` when just logging it.

```
console.log(attrs.ga) -> null
console.log(JSON.parse(attrs.ga) -> Unexpected end of input
```

The name of the directive is `highchartsGauge` and I implement it in my markup like so:

```
<highcharts-gauge ga="{{report.data}}" />
```

Why can I not reference the `ga` attribute in the directive?

Comment: Try doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(attrs))`. Doing `console.log` on an object returns the object itself, which is subject to change (i.e. attrs.ga is potentially being set _after_ the console.log statement).

Comment: I tried that prior to the question as well and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

"Unexpected end of input" is a syntax error, which means you left some statement open (e.g. using `(` but not `)`, or `{` but not `}`).

In your case, that's here:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(attrs.ga)
```

That *should* be:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(attrs.ga))
```

You simply forgot the closing parenthesis.

Comment: I wrote that code on-the-fly when writing up the question, didn't have that in my project.  So that's not the problem, I wish it was an easy one like that.  Thanks though.